# In Swift, how does one determine if two UnsafePointers reference the same memory?

Tags: pointers, swift, equality, unsafe-pointers

I have two variables of type "UnsafePointer<Float>" that should point to two C arrays of floats.

I already know how to access the value of the memory to which they point.

What I don't know how to do, is determine if they both refer to the *same* memory (i.e.: both point to the same address).

**How does one check whether the memory addresses stored by two UnsafePointers are the same?**

Comment: `UnsafePointer<Float>` doesn't look like C. Are you sure about the `c` tag?

Comment: As for your problem, a pointers value is the address of the memory it points to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift, `UnsafePointer<T>` conforms to the `Comparable` protocol, so you can
simply compare the pointers with `==`. Example: A C function

```
float *foo(void);
```

is mapped to Swift as

```
func foo() -> UnsafePointer<Float>
```

and the following code compiles, and tests if two subsequent calls to the function
return the same pointer:

```
let p1 = foo()
let p2 = foo()
if p1 == p2 {
    println("equal")
}
```

As Joachim already said in a comment, a pointers value is the address of the memory it points to. So the pointers being equal means that they point to the same memory address.

Comment: That doesn't compile, Martin "Function produces expected type Int, did you mean to call it with ()" I assume the Int is the memory address if I call it with braces, but I'd like to double-check.

Comment: @Charlesism: It was meant as an *example*. Of course `= ...` does not compile. You have to fill in your pointers.